# Cannot call function on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a beginner in PHP, I want to show a confirm box on a link click but I cannot get any result in that. It gives me error onclick but I cannot read this error because it suddenly refreshes the page. Is there any mistake in single quote?

Is it possible for me to use alert in link tag?

```
echo '<tr><td align="center"><a onclick="confirm return("You Want To Delete?");" href="persontype.php?person_type_id='.$postRow['person_type_id'].'">Delete</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quote, use `javascript:` and it's `return confirm()`, not `confirm return()`

```
echo '<tr><td align="center"><a onclick="javascript: return confirm(\'You Want To Delete?\');" href="persontype.php?person_type_id='.$postRow['person_type_id'].'">Delete</a></td>';
```

I copied your exact php code and modified. The above php code should output the exact functionality you are expecting.

[image]

To show SweetAlert:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">

<?php
echo '<tr><td align="center"><a onclick="javascript: swal({title:\'You Want To Delete?\',   text: \'You really want to delete this user?\',   type: \'warning\',   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: \'#DD6B55\',   confirmButtonText: \'Yes, delete it!\',   cancelButtonText: \'No, cancel plx!\',   closeOnConfirm: false,   closeOnCancel: true }, function(isConfirm){   if (isConfirm) {   window.location.href = \'persontype.php?person_type_id='.$postRow['person_type_id'].'\';   } else {     return false;   } }); return false;" href="persontype.php?person_type_id='.$postRow['person_type_id'].'">Delete</a></td>';
```

Sorry, the code looks ugly in one line, but it works and it's the only way to show sweet alert inside link.

[image]

Comment: me remove "javascript: still it's working where is my mistake can u point out me

Comment: Yes it'll work if you don't use `javascript:`. But using `javascript:` is a convention and a good practice.

Comment: Where is my mistake bro @adnan

Comment: Your main mistake was with the " (double quote) inside another " (double quote).

Comment: is it possible to use sweet alert in link tag?

Comment: Yes possible. Please check my edited answer. As the comment box can't hold the whole code I put it below the original answer. Hope that helps. Please let me know if you need further assistance. Thanks

Comment: why you are using  '\' in script how does it helps.

Comment: It is called escape character. So $test = 'It's cool'; (this is wrong as the ' starts and ends within 'It', the 's cool' after it is cut off. So to escape(ignore) the ' from It's we need to escape the quote so that the string does not end. Correct form is $test = 'It\'s cool';

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it in a wrong way.If you want to `return` what `confirm()` is returning the it should be -

```
onclick="return confirm('You Want To Delete?');"
```

You also need to `escape` the quotes or change them to `'`s for the message. Or you can try with if you want some other checks or other processings -

```
onclick="cnf_delete()"
```

And define the function -

```
function cnf_delete() {
    return confirm('You Want To Delete?');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="confirm('You Want To Delete?');" href="#">Delete</a>
```

Works...

Comment: It is not only showing the message! You have to return the value also.

Comment: Which value and return to where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" href="#">Delete</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    confirm("Press a button!");
}
</script>
```